# Accessing RTP Timestamps from WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtp

I'm currently working on a WebRTC project. We are using Janus Gateway for WebRTC server side recording/transceiving etc.

For a canvas related synchronization, I need to access RTP timestamps of the received video track. I have been searching for a method extensively for a while now.

I've tried getStats function of peer connection, but the timestamps of the stats are the acquisition times. Not packet timestamps.

Also, in W3's standard it says specifically:

> The timestamp of type DOMHighResTimeStamp [HIGHRES-TIME], indicating
>   the most recent time of playout of an RTP packet containing the
>   source. The timestamp is defined in [ HIGHRES-TIME] and corresponds to
>   a local clock.

Which can be accessed via `getContributingSources()` function from `RTCRtpReceiver` object. But I've noticed, that function returns an empty array.

To reproduce:

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/

After you press **Start** and **Call** your camera feed and the peer connection should appear.
After that open up the console and write:

```
const receivers = pc2.getReceivers();
receivers.forEach(receiver => {
    console.log(receiver.getContributingSources());
});
```

My question is, how can I access the received RTP packet's timestamp? Or the last received video RTP timestamp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: Chrome supports standardized stats since version [76](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/Y7TIuNbgP8M/UoXP-RuxAwAJ).

You can't access individual frame timestamps (not in javascript, at least) but [`inbound-rtp`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcstatstype-inbound-rtp) stats seems defintely what you're searching for. The interface [`RTCInboundRtpStreamStats`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/#dom-rtcinboundrtpstreamstats) has `lastPacketReceivedTimestamp` which is defined as:

> lastPacketReceivedTimestamp of type DOMHighResTimeStamp Represents the
>   timestamp at which the last packet was received for this SSRC. This
>   differs from timestamp, which represents the time at which the
>   statistics were generated by the local endpoint.

All modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, safari, Edge) seems to provide some support for `inbound-rtp` stats. Verify if they already provide meaningful values for `lastPacketReceivedTimestamp`. **NOTE**: the specification seems to be quite recent, your mileage may vary. Here is some code:

```js
    rtcpeer.getReceivers()[0].getStats().then(function(stats)
    {
        for (let stat of stats.values())
        {
          if (stat.type === "inbound-rtp")
            console.log(stat.lastPacketReceivedTimestamp);
        }
    });
```

Comment: That project is an old story now, but I will check this out in couple of days and try to provide a resolution. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As said, the specification is probably too new and I'm already verifying scarse support for timestamp information, for example in `outbound-rtp` stats chrome does not expose timestamps and firefox shows strage values. This information may be useful later when hopefully more browser implement it correctly.

Comment: i have google-chrome version 73.0.3683.103. Ran the above code but `lastPacketReceivedTimestamp` seems to be absent ! The spec does not make it mandatory either. The `RTCInboundRtpStreamStats` stat identified through `stat.type == "inbound-rtp"` does not have the attribute/name  `lastPacketReceivedTimestamp`. Looks like this is not made mandatory. Any help to get this attribute for the video track will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ksridhar upgrade at least to chrome 76. They are adding these stats only very recently

Comment: thank you. i did so. rtp timestamps can be obtained through RTCRtpReceiver.getSynchronizationSources. see https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-stats/issues/229#issuecomment-525223463

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @ksridhar in the comments, you can now access the timestamp through `getSynchronizationSources` of the receiver:

```
connection.getReceivers().forEach(receiver => {
  console.log(receiver.getParameters());
  receiver.getSynchronizationSources().forEach(ssrc =>
    console.log(ssrc.rtpTimestamp)); // compare to clockrate
});
```

Note that this is not really a (date-) time stamp. It seems to be samples of the clock rate. For instance, with a video payload that has a clock rate of 90,000, this `rtpTimestamp` will increase by 90,000 every second when everything is flowing smoothly (no lag). You can extract the `clockRate` from the `codecs` returned by `receiver.getParameters()`.

For more details see https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcrtpcontributingsource-rtptimestamp and the RFC section it refers to.